# Add a dummy row when the query returns at least one result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have seen a few SQL questions regarding "how to add a row when none exists" or "how to return a dummy row when no result is found", but I can't figure out a way to get the opposite result. My objective here is to add a row whenever there's at least one result found. However, when no result is found, nothing should be returned.

Given the following `users` table:

```
ID     USERNAME
------------------
1      bob
2      alice
```

And a dummy row (which isn't stored in the DB) :

```
ID     USERNAME
------------------
0      dummy
```

Here is the result I'm trying to get:

```
# Query: find users with ID 1.

ID     USERNAME
------------------
1      bob
0      dummy

# Query: find users with ID 3.

(empty set)

# Query: find users with ID 0.

(empty set)
```

Of course, the dummy row is to be added only once (and not once per actual record). For now, I am working with the following query...

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1
    UNION SELECT 0, 'dummy'
)
```

Yet, this adds the dummy row in all cases, even when the first sub-`SELECT` returns an empty set. Is there any way I could add my row only when necessary?

*Note:* This is a MySQL database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select id, username
from users
where id = 1
union all
select *
from (select 0 as id, 'dummy' as username) t
where exists (select 1 from users where id = 1);
```